# PHP DBconnection Class connection to use in another

Tags: php, oop

I have one DB class in which I am calling mysqli connect in constructor, I want to use this connection in another class. How I can do that, Do i have to reinitialize class first inside the class II ?? Or do I have to Inherit DB Class to class 2 ??
appreciate any guidance.

Thanks in advance,

Sambhav

**Below are Rough outline of both the classes.**

**CLASS I - DB Class**

```
class Db {

    private $dbHost = "";
    private $dbUser = "";
    private $dbPass = "";
    private $dbDatabase = "";

    function __construct() {

        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbDatabase);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Error in connecting to database" . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        //echo "connected to database";
    }

}
```

**class II - The Class trying to use db connection**

```
class MyClass {

    private $details = array();

    public function getDetails() {
        $query = "SELECT `user` FROM `db`.`table`";

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        while ($row == $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //.........
        }
        return $details;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protected property within the class that is trying to use `Db`, for example;

```
class MyClass {

protected $objDb;

public function connectToDb() {
    $this->objDb = new Db();
}
```

Then, within your `getDetails` method, use `$this->` to "access" the `Db` class.

```
$result = $this->objDb->query($query);
```

And usage;

```
$objMyClass = new MyClass();
$objMyClass->connectToDb();
$objMyClass->getDetails();
```

Alternatively, you could put `connectToDb` method within your `__construct()`

Here is the full code: http://harrydenley.com/stackoverflow-25112589/ (Tested on my server and all works. I had to make a few changes, which you can see in the post)

Comment: Hi hd, 

thanks for the answer. you answer looks nice to me but when I tried it(the steps given by you) gave me error "cannot redeclare class ConnectDb in ". I have thoroughly checked I haven't redeclared class anywhere else; The steps are exactly the same suggested by you. 

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: See full code: http://harrydenley.com/stackoverflow-25112589/ (Tested it on my server, all works)

Comment: Great...Thank you Harry :) . This worked as expected, I want to express my sincere gratitude for going extra mile. Many thanks to you. 

Best Regards,
Sambhav