# Create new object in __constructor function PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, object

Can I create a new object in __constructor() ? so then I can use the class in current class method.

Let say I have this class

```
class Config{

  public function configure($data){

  }
}
```

and I want to use `Config` in some of `Myclass` method like this :

```
include 'Config.php'

class Myclass {
   function __construct(){
     $this->conf = new Config();   //just create one config object
   }

   public function method1($data){
     $this->conf->configure($data); //call the configure method
   }


   public function method2(){
     $this->conf->configure($data); //call again the configure method
   }

}
```

can I do like that above. or I must create new object frequently like this below:

```
class Myclass {

  public function method1($data){
    $this->conf = new Config(); //create config object
  }

  public function method2($data){
    $this->conf = new Config(); //create again config object
  }
}
```

Since I was new in writing my own php oop code,I would like to know which method are efficient when I want to create one object and used it in many function . Thanks!

Comment: learn about special object $this. Here If you use $this->conf means you have to declare this property in non-static way to fetch it. i.e `public $conf` or `protected $conf` or `private $conf`

Comment: why not extend the `Config` file?

Comment: sorry I have edited my question . I didn't extend the Config because I just want to use the Config method in some function,not all.

Comment: @MalikPerang - no matter if you extend it or create an instance of it, you will have access to its public variables/methods in any case. Extending has a benefit of getting access to the `protected` properties as well. Choose as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `$conf` first.try it  -

```
include 'Config.php';

class Myclass {

   private $conf;
   function __construct(){
     $this->conf = new Config();   //just create one config object
   }

   public function method1($data){
     $this->conf->configure($data); //call the configure method
   }


   public function method2(){
     $this->conf->configure($data); //call again the configure method
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
protected $objDb;

public function __construct() {
$this->objDb = new Db();
}
```

Please refer [PHP DBconnection Class connection to use in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112589/php-dbconnection-class-connection-to-use-in-another)

See if it helps

Comment: my question is how can I use single declared object in many function.Not how can I connect to the database using class.

Comment: I have given the reference as in the above code new object is being declared inside a method. You could ignore the Database part

Comment: Great..Let's see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly instantiate a new object in the constructor. You can also pass an object into it.

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(BarInterface $bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

There's a whole concept around it called "Dependency Injection".

If you design your classes like this, you can always switch $bar for any other object which implements BarInterface.

Comment: Aha "Dependency Injection" . I must read more about this. btw,thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions given above, you can also extend it making the `Config` file a super class.

```
class Config{
  // create a constructor method
  public function __construct() {
    // some initialisation here
  }

  public function configure($data){

  }
}
```

Then you can extend this class in your code to make use of `inheritance`.

```
include 'Config.php'

class Myclass extends Config {
   function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();   //initialise the parent class
     // more initialisation
   }

   public function method1($data){
     $this->configure($data); //call the configure method
   }


   public function method2(){
     $this->configure($data); //call again the configure method
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.